# Referring a parent node in XML while XSLT reduces performance drastically

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, sax, saxon

While doing XSLT optimization, I figured out that by avoiding parent node look-up the XSLT run duration reduces from 1 hour to ~20 seconds.

I just avoided below xsl line by passing relevant params to take the required decision and the performance just boosted.

```
<xsl:if test="parent::node() = /test">
...
</xsl:if>
```

I am using saxon8.jar library to perform XSLT that uses SAX-based XML parsing.

I understand that SAX is push-based, so referring back is costly. But, would like to get some more insight on the cost and the algorithm involved here.

Also, in my XSL I am referring same forward nodes many times using Xpath at different steps of execution. Then, why this did not turn into a bottleneck like the way referring to the parent node did?

Comment: I do not understand the actual test you have above. It means if the parent node is equal to the child node "test" of the current context. Its is unclear that test is even correct. Are you wanting to see if the current parent node is named test? Or what? I could see how this type of test (comparing the entire current parent tree to another child tree) would be huge (and likely never true).

Comment: @Kevin, I am performing a normal XSL transformation. The input XML has many nested child elements in a deep hierarchical manner. So, then I am executing the mentioned code from some child element in the hierarchy. This if-block is actually verifying that the current child element's parent node is the root element "test".

Comment: Your reference to SAX suggests that you've got an incorrect mental model of the way XSLT works. Unless you're using a streaming processor, which is unlikely, the XSLT operates on an in-memory tree representation of the XML. The fact that you supplied it as a SAX stream is irrelevant.

Comment: @Michael...thanks for this insight...i got the impression of moving back n forth for sax-based xslt because when i used DOM source the memory footprint increased...So if I understand you correctly, before transformation starts, saxon reads complete xml (by sax parsing) and keep it in-memory in a TinyTree data structure. Later, during transformation, this TinyTree is referred to evaluate XPath results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you meant `parent::node() is /test`. That, is you want to know if the parent node is the same node as the /test node. That would be a very fast test. But using "=" is slow: it forms the string value of parent::node(), and the string-value of /test, and compares them as strings. The string value of /test is the concatenation of all the text nodes in the document, so it involves searching the whole document and building a potentially very large string.

Answer (score 0):

I would test a count of the ancestors. A nodal comparison like you are doing is comparing everything in the tree. If you are only interested in second level nodes (and not that the whole tree is equal to another tree) then I would expect something like:

```
<xsl:when test="count(ancestor::node()) = 2"/>
```

or maybe better performance is

```
<xsl:when test="count(parent::node() | /test = 1)"/>
```

Would be better. Just my guess.

Comment: @Kevin...thanks for your answer, but i am not looking for any solution, I already have it...Rather, I would like to understand the complexity and algo involved to move back and forth (referring parent node) in the sax-based xslt.